# When an intersection of open sets is a singleton

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

I need to prove that if $F=\{x\}\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ then $\exists$ a collection of open subsets $U_i$, i.e. $\{U_1, U_2,...,...\}$, such that $\bigcap_i U_i = \{x\}$.

My approach:

Consider the collection of open balls $B_{1/n}(x)$, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty B_{1/n}{(x)}=\{x\}$.

Do you think this is rigorous enough, or should there be further clarification in the proof?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Your solution is correct but your teacher may require a proof that your solution is correct. You must show that $x$ is in the intersection and that if $y\ne x$ then it is not in the intersection.

Comment: @JohnDouma, would it be OK to argue like this? Let $y\in \bigcap\limits_{1/n}^\infty B_{1/n}(x)$. Then $y\in \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} B_{1/n}(x)=B_0(x)=\{x\}$. I'm a bit concerned about the $B_0(x)$.

Comment: $x\in B_{\frac{1}{n}}(x)$ for all $n$ so $x$ is in the intersection. If $y\ne x$ then choose $N$ such that $\frac{1}{N}\lt d(x,y)$. Then $y\notin B_{\frac{1}{N}}(x)$ so $y$ is not in the intersection.

Comment: It depends who your audience is.  Note that the result is valid in any metric space.